# Search the exact word instead with SOLR

Tags: solr4, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My query is `pension paid united nation` when I do the full text search its giving top results which contains `national` word instead of nation word, but I want the result should contains all the words in the query, but don't want `national` instead of that wants `nation` word should present in the documents.

How to achieve this with SOLR?

Comment: An excerpt of your schema would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a stemmer filter (e.g. `PorterStemFilterFactory` or `SnowballPorterFilterFactory`) configured in the field type of the field you are querying.

Remove that or user another field. If you need the stemmed field for something else, you can add a new field and field type without stemmer and copy the content there using

```
<copyField source="..." dest="..."/>
```